# Proof of a relation in Dirac's 1927 paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-electrodynamics

I was reading Dirac's paper "The quantum theory of the emission and absorption of radiation".

I am confused regarding the following relation in the paper:
$
e^{{\pm i\theta_r \over h}} f(N_1',N_2', ... N_r', ... ) = e^{\mp \partial \over \partial N_r'}f(N_1', N_2',.. . N_r',... )
=f (N_1', N_2',..., N_r' \mp 1,... )$

I'm only confused regarding

$ e^{\mp \partial \over \partial N_r'}f(N_1', N_2',.. . N_r',... )
=f (N_1', N_2',..., N_r' \mp 1,... )$

pg 10 in his paper

https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1927.0039

Is there a proof for this statement?

Dirac hasn't given a proof, is it proved in any earlier paper? Is it a definition?

Comment: I suspect that if you want this question to be reopened you'll have to type out what exactly $f$ is, what is stated about $f$ in the paper, etc. In general people don't like to click links and have to track down definitions in a paper, they'd rather it all be self contained in the question statement itself.

Comment: Actually I think this can be answered without knowing what $f$ is (assuming it is sufficiently smooth to do all the differentiations Dirac wants to do :))

Comment: But for what it is worth I suspect (without reading the reference) that $f$ is a probability distribution over occupation numbers for the states of a quantum system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an application of a mathematical theorem (which is not nearly as bad as it looks).

Let's start of with a function of one variable, $f(x)$, for simplicity.
First, we define the derivative operator as
\begin{equation}
D \equiv \frac{d}{dx}
\end{equation}
Then I claim that $D$ obeys the following identity for any (sufficiently well-behaved) function $f$ and constant $\delta$:
\begin{equation}
e^{\delta D} f(x) = f(x+\delta)
\end{equation}
This can be proven by expanding the exponential as a Taylor series, and realizing that the result is the Taylor series expansion of $f(x+\delta)$:
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{\delta D}f(x)  &=& \left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\delta^n D^n}{n!} \right] f(x)  \\
&=& \left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\delta^n}{n!} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \right] f(x) \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\delta^n f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} \\
&=& f(x+\delta)
\end{eqnarray}
As a special case of this identity, note that
\begin{equation}
e^{\pm D}f(x) = f(x\pm 1)
\end{equation}

Now we turn to the multivariate case. The generalization is straightforward. Defining the partial derivative operator
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}_r \equiv \frac{\partial }{\partial N_r}
\end{equation}
we have that
\begin{equation}
e^{\delta \mathcal{D}_r} f(N_1, N_2, ..., N_k) = f(N_1,N_2, ..., N_r+\delta,...,N_k)
\end{equation}
Or, as a special case,
\begin{equation}
e^{\pm \mathcal{D}_r} f(N_1, N_2, ..., N_k) = f(N_1,N_2, ..., N_r\pm 1,...,N_k)
\end{equation}
which is the identity you wanted.